# How to save geojson data from OSRM to a text file

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, osrm

I am using leaflet routine machine and mapbox to get routes. All works fine and I can console.log the route out but ideally I would like to save the geojson data to a text file so I can do testing without calling the API every time and I can change things too. I am using javascript with a browser, I can only see example in node.js, is this the only way?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) library to save files on the client-side

```
// add the geojson to the map
const geoJson = L.geoJson(freeBus).addTo(map);

// use external library to save geojson
const saveTxt = (content, filename) => {
  const file = filename + ".json";
  saveAs(new File([JSON.stringify(content)], file, {
      type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
    }), file);
};

// invoke the function by passing geojson to be saved
// and .txt file name
saveTxt(geoJson.toGeoJSON(), "test");
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/q2rj0p024)